# ActiveMQ Artemis cluster failover support

Tags: activemq-artemis

Currently, I'm using ActiveMQ, and planning to migrate the system to ActiveMQ Artemis. Currently, I have 3 producers and 3 consumers with just one ActiveMQ server/broker.

I want to create 3 nodes of the cluster with Artemis and make a load balancing. I've read [this document](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html), but couldn't find any information related to what happens if one of my nodes in the cluster fails.

Automatically Artemis cluster starts load balancing with the other two servers? Or should I create a backup server for each of the nodes in my cluster? (Means total 6 server 3 main 3 slave)

Comment: Why do you want to create 3 nodes when you only have 3 producers and 3 consumers? Clustering is designed to increase message throughput via horizontal scaling when dealing with a large number of clients. That doesn't seem to be your use-case.

Comment: Ah sorry @JustinBertram, yes you are absolutely right. Since we are not having a performance problem with ActiveMQ, and our consumers/producers won't increase in near future, avoid from clustering, for now, will be best.
Just going active/passive, or active/passive/passive seems enough for our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering and fail-over are related but distinct concepts in ActiveMQ Artemis.

With a cluster messages can be load-balanced across nodes, but each node "owns" the messages on it. If a node in a cluster fails then the messages on that node will no longer be available to clients. Clustering is designed to increase message throughput via horizontal scaling when dealing with a large number of clients.

Fail-over provides high-availability of messages so that if a node fails then its backup will take over and ensure the messages from the failed node are still available to clients. See more details in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/ha.html).

If you think might pursue a clustered configuration I would encourage you to benchmark your application with a single broker. The performance of ActiveMQ Artemis is quite good. It can handle millions of messages per second in certain use-cases. The performance of a single broker may be enough to support your use-case. Don't blindly cluster your brokers as you may needlessly complicate your configuration and maintenance and waste resources.